# How to prevent re-rendering of react state with firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase storage to get image files.
Even if I try to get one image file, I still get at least 2 re-renders.
How can I only have it render once?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {ref, getStorage, getDownloadURL,
        getMetadata, listAll} from "firebase/storage";
import {storage, db} from "../../utils/firebase";

const AdminProject = () => {
  const storage = getStorage();

  useEffect(() => {

      const fetchData = async () => {
        const img = await ref(storage, 'images/godot.png');
        const res = await getMetadata(img);

        console.log("RES", res);        
      };

      fetchData();      
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="admin-project">
      <div id="admin-project-container">

        <h3>Admin Project</h3>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AdminProject
```

Comment: Rerenders in react are fine. It's ok to rerender the component several times.

Comment: One option is to use React's Suspense feature along with a compatible library to handle the async load in a Suspense-friendly way. Here, depending on what you plan to do with the image, you might want to load it for display in a child component. Or if you show it a lot, you might want to cache it.